# Sql query display wrong values when search for a reservation given a time period

Tags: mysql, sql

here is a screen shot of the table bookings
[bookin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biNi7.png)

here is the query im using,

```
SELECT * FROM BOOKINGS WHERE not
CheckIn >= '01:00:00' and CheckOut <= '02:00:00' and
CheckOut <= '01:00:00' and CheckIn <= '01:00:00' or
CheckIn >= '02:00:00'
```

when i  give a specific time period i want to return all the available rooms in that given time period.

example - i want to get all the rooms that are available from 1pm to 2pm , and i should only get the room 104. but i get the room 101 as available. the room 101 has a booking from 1pm to 2pm and another booking from 2pm to 3pm. the query ignores the 2pm to 3pm booking and shows it as available.

here is the screen shot of the above query 
[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMaYf.png)

the result is wrong, room 101 cant be available

**The output that i want is, when i give a time period i want to return all the available rooms example**

```
 test a: 1pm to 2pm available rooms 103 and 104 
 test b: 1.30pm to 2pm available rooms 103 and 104 
 test c: 1.30pm to 2.30pm available rooms 104 
 test d: 1.00pm to 2.30pm available rooms 104
```

i would like to know how the problem can be solved, and what sort of approach is needed. i have also used join statements and a separate table storing room numbers, but still no luck.

code for the above table creation -

```
CREATE TABLE `bookings` (
`BookingID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`RoomID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`CheckIn` time DEFAULT NULL,
`CheckOut` time DEFAULT NULL
);

 INSERT INTO `bookings` (`BookingID`, `RoomID`, `CheckIn`, `CheckOut`) 
 VALUES
 (1, 101, '01:00:00', '02:00:00'),
 (2, 101, '02:00:00', '03:00:00'),
 (3, 103, '02:00:00', '03:00:00'),
 (4, 104, '03:00:00', '04:00:00');
```

**EDIT**

the following query works for the above mentioned scenarios

```
SELECT * FROM BOOKINGS WHERE RoomID NOT IN 
(
  SELECT RoomID FROM BOOKINGS WHERE
  ( CheckIn >= '01:30:00' and CheckIn < '03:30:00') or
  ( CheckIn < '01:30:00' and CheckOut >= '03:30:00')
)
```

**EDIT 2**
when the above query is used to check for available rooms from 2.30pm to 3.30pm, it fails.

Comment: Your desired output is not clear. Kindly add desired output to your question.

Comment: i have updated the post with my requirements, its in bold

Comment: I think you can do better than the accepted answer

Comment: how would that be?

Comment: @Jevin two time windows a and b overlap if and only if start_a < stop_b and start_b < stop_a.  Stated another way, if each window starts before the other one stops, they overlap; otherwise, they don't.  You only need those two comparisons.  Doing more than those two means you are either making an unnecessary/redundant comparison, or an incorrect/logically-invalid comparison. Comparing start to start or stop to stop is the wrong comparison. An available room from 2:30 to 3:30 has no single event stopping after 2:30 **and** starting before 3:30.  Rooms 101, 103, and 104 are thus all busy.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot  can you tell me how i can get the rooms that are BOOKED when given a time period.     example table -    
id- 1     |  IN - 1pm     |  OUT - 2pm  |

when i specify a time like bookings from 1.30pm to 2.30pm the booking 1 should be displayed or if i want 1pm to 2.30pm the booking 1 should be displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic here is deceptively simple.

To find a conflicting/overlapping time window, you need to find entries with both a check-**in** time that is *before* your desired **end** time, and a check-**out** time that is *after* your desired **start** time.  You compare start to end, not start to start or end to end.

This may seem like you're not testing enough conditions, but this is all you need.  Consider this plain-language explanation:

*If you check in before I check out,* and *if I check in before you check out, then we are necessarily both here at the same time.  Otherwise, we are necessarily not.*

So, to find all rooms that have bookings that conflict with a proposed booking from 01:00:00 to 02:30:00...

```
SELECT DISTINCT RoomID FROM bookings 
 WHERE CheckIn  < '02:30:00'
   AND CheckOut > '01:00:00';
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/341305/14

To find available rooms, you'd select from your table of rooms `WHERE RoomID NOT IN (/* the query above */)`.

Answer (score 1):

No matter if you just want to view a single query, or you can create a function for dynamic query.

But the logic should be this-

lets say you want to check availability for checkIN = start_time and checkOUT =  end_time,

```
SELECT * FROM BOOKINGS WHERE RoomID NOT IN 
    (
      SELECT RoomID FROM BOOKINGS WHERE
      ( CheckIn >= start_time and CheckIn < end_time) or
      ( CheckIn < start_time and CheckOut > end_time)
    )
```

Comment: for functions and procedures, you can refer to - http://javajee.com/mysql-stored-procedure-and-stored-function-examples

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use something like this -

```
   SELECT * FROM BOOKINGS WHERE RoomID NOT IN 
    (
      SELECT RoomID FROM BOOKINGS WHERE
      ( CheckIn >= '01:00:00' and CheckIn < '02:00:00') or
      ( CheckIn < '01:00:00' and CheckOut > '02:00:00')
    )
```

Don't forget to use the brackets, it always is better to use them.

Here, the logic is first in the subquery we select all the RoomID which are book in the time 1:00:00-2:00:00, then we in outer query we exclude the Rooms and display the remaining rooms

**For your upadted question**, for each test case you need different queries right?

For test a: the above code is the answer.

For test b:

```
SELECT * FROM BOOKINGS WHERE RoomID NOT IN 
    (
      SELECT RoomID FROM BOOKINGS WHERE
      ( CheckIn >= '01:30:00' and CheckIn < '02:00:00') or
      ( CheckIn < '01:30:00' and CheckOut > '02:00:00')
    )
```

For test c:

```
SELECT * FROM BOOKINGS WHERE RoomID NOT IN 
        (
          SELECT RoomID FROM BOOKINGS WHERE
          ( CheckIn >= '01:30:00' and CheckIn < '02:30:00') or
          ( CheckIn < '01:30:00' and CheckOut > '02:30:00')
        )
```

Similarly, for test d:

```
SELECT * FROM BOOKINGS WHERE RoomID NOT IN 
    (
      SELECT RoomID FROM BOOKINGS WHERE
      ( CheckIn >= '01:00:00' and CheckIn < '02:30:00') or
      ( CheckIn < '01:00:00' and CheckOut > '02:30:00')
    )
```

Comment: when i run it, i get the results -  
BookingID RoomID CheckIn CheckOut 
2                   101 02:00:00 03:00:00 
3                   103 02:00:00 03:00:00 
4                   104 03:00:00 04:00:00                                                            but the booking 2 (room number 101)  cant be available, as i mentioned above in my post, that room cannot be available as their is a booking for that room from 1pm to 2pm

Comment: thank you, i ran it the issue mentioned above is solved but when you enter 1.30pm to 2pm or 1.30 to 2.30pm the booked rooms are shown as available

Comment: you mean, if you insert values with 1:30:00 in the table, or in the query ?

Comment: i have updated the post with my requirements, its in bold

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: hi, all the tests should be checked in one query

Comment: hi i guess this query is working so far, i added an equal to the checkout -                                          
    SELECT * FROM BOOKINGS WHERE RoomID NOT IN 
    (
      SELECT RoomID FROM BOOKINGS WHERE
      ( CheckIn >= '01:30:00' and CheckIn < '03:00:00') or
      ( CheckIn < '01:30:00' and CheckOut >= '03:00:00')
    )

Comment: oh yes.
btw for you new updated question, you need use functions, if you are using some server hosts and need the dynamic queries

Comment: Event A overlaps Event B if Event A starts before Event B finishes, and finishes after Event B starts. The rest is noise.

Comment: the query fails when i check from 2.30pm to 3.30pm

Comment: If you are using only MySQL query, you need to you different conditions according to the times you need available room for.

Comment: how is that possible? the query should execute when i give the checkin and checkout values and then it will check for available rooms

Comment: For that you need to use functions or procedures

Comment: You can read about that here - http://mobile.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3569846/MySQL-Stored-Functions.htm

Answer (score 0):

First find the rooms that are busy during the required time frame and exclude them from the list of all rooms in the hotels.  It should give you the required result.

Here is the oracle query.

```
 select roomid from bookings where roomid not in (
  select roomid from bookings where '13-10-17 01:15:00' between checkin and  checkout );
```

Comment: ran this, select * from bookings where roomid not in (
  select roomid from bookings where 
  ('01:00:00' between checkin and  checkout) or 
  ('03:30:00' between CheckIn and CheckOut)

  )   still and error.  how can i seperate this into another table. i guess the table is wrong?